# Error: VNDK library: libandroid_net's ABI has EXTENDING CHANGES

Tags: c++, c, android-source

I am setting up an environment to run AOSP code on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and got the error "error: VNDK library: libandroid_net's ABI has EXTENDING CHANGES". Please help me to resolve this. I have searched for hours but didn't get the solution.

I have done following things:

1. Installed required packages: `sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip`
2. Installed community-maintained default set of udev rules for all Android devices: `apt-get install adb`
3. Install repo: https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading.html

   - mkdir ~/bin
   - PATH=~/bin:$PATH
   - curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
   - chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
4. Initializing a Repo client

   - mkdir WORK
   - cd WORK
   - git config --global user.name "Your Name"
   - git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   - repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
5. Installed pixel 3 XL binaries which include google-devices and qcom blueline. Used Extractor and ./*.sh command to extract them.
6. Copied qcom extracted vendor folder into Source Code and then copied pixel 3 xl vendor folder. Meged and replaced in all dialogs.
7. Run `make clobber` to clean the build directory.
8. Run `. build/envsetup.sh` to initialize the environment.
9. Run `lunch aosp_arm-eng` to select your run target as asop_arm BUILD with eng BUILDTYPE.
10. Run `make -j16` to build the code.
11. Got build error:

    - `error: VNDK library: libandroid_net's ABI has EXTENDING CHANGES`
    - `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000e7400000, 83886080, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)`
    - `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000cac00000, 73400320, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)`

For 'Not enough space' error: I am setting cache and configuring jack

- `export USE_CCACHE=1` to enable compiler cache
- Failed to do `prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 15G` because there is no ccache folder exists.
- `export ANDROID_JACK_VM_ARGS="-Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation"` to configure Jack.

For resolving the VNDK issue I am not sure by may be binaries I have included are not correct so I have deleted the vendor folder that contains Pixel 3 XL binaries.

I am a newbie for this task and just started a week ago to look into this.
Please suggest.
Thank you in advance.